# addSubview not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
// Create and add a sub view
CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
UIView *a_sub_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : viewRect];

[window addSubview : a_sub_view];
```

After adding the above 3 lines of code, xcode produces no errors or warnings.  But the sub-view is not showing at all.  The sample program seems to be running exactly as before.  Hope that somebody knowledgable could help.

Comment: Is that actually exactly your code?  If so, `a_sub_view` is a plain `UIView`, which doesn't actually draw anything.  You need to instantiate a custom subclass or some other built-in subclass such as `UIButton`.

Comment: What kind of object is `window`?

Comment: window is UIWindow, before that I tried the "addSubview" to the base UIView of window, but also "no show".

Comment: @Daniel, you are right.  UIView objects do not do anything by itself.  The subview shows up after adding the statement : a_sub_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;   // Thanks ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find it useful to set the background color so I know where the view is and the boundaries.

```
a_sub_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In your example, you're create an empty view so you won't 'see' anything.

Answer (score 3):

window expects a viewcontrollers view to be added.

you can then add subviews to the current view.

so in your example use:

```
[self.view addSubview:a_sub_view];
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this in order to "find" the window:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[window addSubview:myView];
```

This also worked for me, but it is a bit uglier:

```
[self.navigationController.tabBarController.view addSubview:myView];
```

To explain the second one, I had to "follow" the controllers back up to the "top" view. (My application has a tab bar with a navigation controller inside the current tab.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with iOS 5 & above , you have to do as below:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubView:viewObject];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.view addSubView: a_sub_view];
```